# p4 list opened files that are shelved

Tags: perforce

I don't want the changelists; I want the actual files that are shelved. So the results should look like the results of `p4 opened` but filtered to show only the files that are shelved.

Anyone know how to do this in a few commands? (Preferably one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get it down to less than this, but maybe this will help as a starting point:

```
for cl in `p4 -ztag changes -u your.name -s shelved | \
    grep -oP '(?<=^\.{3} change )\d+'`
do
    p4 describe -Ss $cl | grep -E '^\.{3}'
done | sort | uniq
```

This does a `p4 describe -S` on each of your shelved changelists, but tries to only show the files. It might be a bit fragile. It should look like:

```
... //depot/yourfile.txt#4 edit
... //depot/otherfile.txt#5 edit
```